# C# naming convention for extension methods for interface

Tags: .net, interface, naming-conventions, extension-methods

I typically name my C# interfaces as `IThing`.  I'm creating an extension method class for `IThing`, but I don't know what to name it.  On one hand, calling it `ThingExtensions` seems to imply it is an extension class to some `Thing` class instead of to the `IThing` interface.  It also makes the extension class be sorted away from the interface it extends, when viewing files alphabetically.  On the other hand, naming it `IThingExtensions` makes it look like it is an interface itself, instead of an extension class for an interface.  What would you suggest?

**Edit:**  there is not a `Thing` class that implements `IThing`, in response to some of the comments.

Comment: Should be migrated to [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com), because it doesn't deal with a coding problem, but rather pertains to development practice (how to name extension methods).

Comment: Came here looking for a clear winning answer and was actually not surprised not to find one...  I was forced to upvote both your question and **both** Reed's and Jared's answers!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I definitely prefer the name `ThingExtensions` over `IThingExtensions`.  The reason being that to most programmers an `I` prefix on a type implies that it is an interface.  This is both a very common pattern and part of the .Net Design Guidelines.

Adding an `I` prefix for the extension method case breaks both assumptions and established guidelines.

There is also precedence for this in [the Base Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145045.aspx).  The majority of the extension methods available for [`IEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) are contained in the type [`Enumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx).

Comment: I'm imagining that there's a class called `Thing` that implements `IThing`, therefore it would be confusing if it was called `ThingExtensions` but worked on `IThing`'s. But, @Sarah Vessels does not specify this...

Comment: @klausbyskov:  there actually isn't a `Thing` class that implements `IThing`.  I'll update my question.

Comment: I would think the "Extensions" suffix kind of removes this ambiguity?

Comment: We can't "reserve" objects that begin with "I" strictly for interfaces.  Example: class Integrations, class Interrupts, class InsufficientMemoryException ...

Answer (score 24):

I, personally, would use `IThingExtensions`.

From a usability standpoint, the end user never sees this class - they only include it's namespace.  If the namespace is the same as `IThing`, then it doesn't matter - they'll already have it.

That being said, I think that the fact these are extensions for any `IThing` makes `IThingExtensions` the most clear.  If you have a `Thing` class, calling this `ThingExtensions` may seem ambiguous (are you extending the interface or the implementation itself?).

That being said, the framework uses a very different approach.  The framework's approach is to use a class named `Thing` to extend `IThing`.  For examples, see [Enumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx) (extending `IEnumerable`) and [Queryable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.aspx) (extending `IQueryable`).  This would also be a very good option.

Comment: I follow the framework's approach in my projects. Hasn't lead to any nasty side-effects yet.

Comment: @Programming: It works great, provided you don't have a default implementation for `IThing` that's named `Thing`...

Comment: I still don't like this approach because it violates the design guidelines for type naming.  In particular only prefix type names with an I if it's actually an interface.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229040.aspx

Comment: @JaredPar: Yes, but unfortunately, the design guidelines don't really have any guidance for naming Extension method classes - they really just talk about when to use them (ie: http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2009/01/12/framework-design-guidelines-extension-methods.aspx)  Using Thing is my preference unless you're making a Thing class - in which case, ThingExtensions becomes confusing...  Hopefully, there will be official guidance on this at some point.

Comment: Luckily, however, the user never uses the class name, so the extension method class name is (effectively) an implementation detail, and not part of the API.  The user only "uses" and "knows" the namespace name directly.

Comment: @Reed agreed they are a bit silent on the naming convention.  But in the absence of one I usually fall back to precedence and for the BCL and most of VS APIs the precedence is `ThingExtensions`.  Additionally it seems unlikely the design guidelines would come out in favor of `IThingExtensions` because it would mean too much existing code was no longer up to par.  My guess is they will continue to remain silent on the subject

Comment: @JaredPar: Does the BCL use "ThingExtensions" anywhere?  Every BCL class seems to use "Thing"... This is my preference (and what I typically do) unless there is a "Thing" class, in which case it gets confusing :(

Comment: @Reed,  Not that I know of.  The new Visual Studio APIs have the `ThingExtensions` pattern in several places.

Comment: @JaredPar `System.Web.Mvc.Html` has plenty, but the name doesn't imply the extended class. Rather, it groups the extension methods by subject, such as `FormExtensions` or `ChildActionExtensions`. There is also `AjaxRequestExtensions` at `System.Web.Mvc`, which extends `HttpRequestBase`. All of theses didn't exist at the time the above comments were added, though.

Comment: Roslyn has class ISymbolExtensions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.isymbolextensions?view=roslyn-dotnet

Answer (score 4):

I would prefer putting it in a folder (and namespace) called `Extensions` and naming it `IThingExtensions`.

Answer (score 4):

Most programmers I know put all of their extension methods for an application in a static class called `ExtensionMethods` (or something like that), *regardless of the class the extensions modify*,  and then they put this class into their *main program namespace*.

Their rationale is that, if you put the extension method in the same namespace as the class it modifies, you can confuse the method with the methods that are part of the actual class, which suggests that the extension method is part of the original functionality when it isn't.

Their isn't universal agreement on this, of course.  See here: [How do you manage the namespaces of your extension methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520446/how-do-you-manage-the-namespaces-of-your-extension-methods)

Comment: If you want to share those extension methods across several apps you will have to search , copy and paste the desired extension methods into your working project. not good.

Answer (score 4):

I've taken a slightly different approach, and rather than suffix with `Extension` reversed the naming strategy to *prefix* the class containing the extension methods with `Extend`; my rationale is as follows:

- As pointed out in [Reed Copsey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2700720/409279), very (*very*) seldom will client code reference the containing class directly as the very point of extension methods is to emulate reference methods. They won't see the classes, so your class naming convention choice should have insignificant impact.
- The classes must be `static`, and thus you'll never instantiate them. Therefore you never end up with the semantic oddity of `new ExtendThing()` as far as naming is concerned.
- All of your `Extend*` classes are visually grouped with alpha file sorting.
- And with respect to your question specifically, there isn't any interface naming prefix confusion; you can have `ExtendThing` *and* `ExtendIThing` and (IMO) their intent and target is clear.

---

```
namespace MyCompany.Extensions
{
    public static class ExtendObject { }

    public static class ExtendDateTime { }

    public static class ExtendIEnumerable { }
}
```

Comment: seems nice way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any standard convention for this.  I would use either ThingExtensions or ThingInterfaceExtensions.  I would stay away from IThingExtensions as you also suggested.